# to post message on Facebook application user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application related to Facebook in which i want log-in user can send message to any  user from the application  even if that user is not friend with him.
i used  method: 'stream.publish' with target_id:selected users id.
by this it is posting the message on target_ids wall only if he is a Facebook friend.
So please help over this.

Thank you

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking here - could you clarify and give an example of your code and the error message you're receiving?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible.  [stream.publish](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/) only allows posting on the app user's friends' Walls.  There is no way to post to the Wall of a non-friend.

You *can* send a request to the user's friends or to a non-friend who has the app installed:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/